# Append key value pair to a dictionary

Tags: python

Is it possible to append key-value pairs to a dictionary?

For example, I want a dictionary like this: `a = {4:"Hello", 1:"World"}` can that be done using dictionaries? If it can't, is there an alternate data structure that can do that?

I want it ordered in order I add them. In this case, I added the key-value pair `4:"Hello"` first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from collections import OrderedDict
order_dict = OrderedDict()
order_dict[4] = "Hello"
order_dict[3] = "World"
order_dict[5] = "Bah"
print order_dict
```

Outputs:

```
OrderedDict([(4, 'Hello'), (3, 'World'), (5, 'Bah')])
```

Print key and values:

```
for key, value in order_dict.iteritems() :
    print key, value
```

Outputs:

```
4 Hello
3 World
5 Bah
```

Comment: This is probably what I'm looking for. How would I print a single key value pair? Say, the 2 key-value pair?

Comment: @stack Check my updated answer.

Comment: @stack - Maybe you could read some documentation or tutorial materials?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I did. I just wanted the answer to be complete before accepting it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can.

From the module collections, use OrderedDict to get the sequence of adding keys retained.

Comment: Write an example that shows how to use an OrderedDict in this case.

Comment: Isn't the answer to OP's first question "No"? This answers their second question about what to do instead.

Answer (score 0):

use `collections.OrderedDict` to have ordered dictionaries:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> original = OrderedDict({1:"world"})
>>> new = OrderedDict({4:"hello"})
>>> new.update(original)
>>> new
# OrderedDict([(4, 'hello'), (1, 'World')])
```

This would work only for additions at front. For insertions at random locations, see [Borja's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34067926/1682131)